# How to rewrite X-Forwarded-Groups

Tags: apache, ldap

Apache 2.4 on Windows Server 2016 as reverse proxy with module mod_authnz_sspi.
Have to set some RequestHeaders, here are the relevant parts of httpd.conf:

```
<Location />
    AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
    AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative On
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    LDAPReferrals Off
    AuthLDAPMaxSubGroupDepth 2
    AuthLDAPRemoteUserAttribute sAMAccountName
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://lan.domain.de:389/DC=lan,DC=domain,DC=de?sAMAccountName,memberOf,mail,displayName"


    AuthLDAPBindDN someuser
    AuthLDAPBindPassword somepasswd
    #Require ldap-group CN=Users,DC=lan,DC=domain,DC=de
    Require ldap-attribute ObjectClass="person"
    AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
    AuthType SSPI
    AuthName "Sonar"
    SSPIAuth On
    SSPIOfferSSPI On
    SSPIAuthoritative On
    SSPIDomain LAN
    SSPIOmitDomain On
    SSPIPackage Negotiate
    Require valid-sspi-user
</Location> 

SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
SSLCertificateFile "E:/Apache/conf/ssl/server.cer"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "E:/Apache/conf/ssl/server.key"
SSLCACertificateFile "E:/Apache/conf/ssl/ca-bundle.crt"
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Login %{AUTHORIZE_sAMAccountName}e
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Groups %{AUTHORIZE_memberof}e
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Email %{AUTHORIZE_mail}e
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Name %{AUTHORIZE_displayName}e
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
RemoteIPInternalProxy 127.0.0.1
ServerName  SomeServer
```

Problem is, the groups come as ';' separated DNs like that, don't know another way to get the groups for user as 'memberOf'

```
CN=Group1,OU=someou,OU=someotherou,DC=lan,DC=domain,DC=de;CN=Group2,OU=someou,OU=someotherou,DC=lan,DC=domain,DC=de;...
```

but the application needs the CNs from those groups separated by ',' would be Group1,Group2 in that example - how to achieve that ?

Any possibility with filter or sub expressions in the ldap URL ?
Is it possible to rewrite the X-Forwarded-Groups accordingly ?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution with [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html), posting it for other users with the same problem.

httpd.conf

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

[...]

RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Groups %{AUTHORIZE_memberof}e
RequestHeader edit* X-Forwarded-Groups CN=([^,]+),[^;]+ $1
RequestHeader edit* X-Forwarded-Groups ; ,
```

edit* with regexp and $1 means all matches of CN=... ; should be replaced with the value of CN.
In the second edit*' the separator ';' is replaced with ','

Works like a charm now.